# How to Pass Pandas Dataframe and Column to a Function

Tags: python, function, pandas, dataframe

So I have a large amount of columns within a pandas dataframe and I need to pass groups of them through a function. The function is large but I'll create an example below. I am not sure how to pass the reference of df.varName to the function without getting the issue of the variable not being defined. When I try a function such as:

```
def bianco2(df, varX, varT):
    stdX = np.std(df.varX)
    stdT = np.std(df.varT)
    newVar = stdX + stdT
    return newVar
```

I get the error that varX isn't defined. So I wrote the function where I would pass the whole phrase:

```
def bianco3(varX, varT):
    stdX = np.std(varX)
    stdT = np.(varT)
    newVar = stdX + stdT
    return newVar
```

Where "varX = df.varX".

This worked but isn't practical for a large number of variables because I would still have to manually update each varX and varT. So I tried creating a list of variables in the format df.varX and then using a for loop to pass the list of variables. The issue is python sees it as a string and not a reference. I looked at using functools.partial but was unsuccessful.

Any ideas on how to write this in a simple format and be able to pass panda columns to a function?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. How would you call `bianco2`? Try posting a [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to try this ?

```
def bianco2(df, varX, varT):
    stdX = np.std(df[varX])
    stdT = np.std(df[varT])
    newVar = stdX + stdT
    return newVar

print bianco2(df,'Customer','Policy')
```

input

```
   Policy  Customer  Employee CoveredDate   LapseDate
0     123      1234      1234  2011-06-01  2013-01-01
1     124      1234      1234  2016-01-01  2013-01-01
2     124      5678      5555  2014-01-01  2013-01-01
```

output

```
  2095.39309492
```

Comment: Thanks Shijo! That should simplify my issue.